# 2D Matrix value update in python

Tags: python, matrix, memory-management

I created simple program to update value in 2D matrix, But the code changes the value of other places as well.

```
row=3
col=4
matrix=[[0]*col]*row
print(matrix)
matrix[1][2]=4
print(matrix)
```

but it gives the following output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 4, 0]]
```

Comment: This link may help you: https://snakify.org/en/lessons/two_dimensional_lists_arrays/#section_2

Answer (score 1):

As from the comment:
https://snakify.org/en/lessons/two_dimensional_lists_arrays/#section_2

> The reason is, [0] * m returns just a reference to a list of m zeros, but not a list.

Just define your matrix like this:

```py
row=3
col=4
matrix = [[0 for c in range(col)] for r in range(row)]
print(matrix)
matrix[1][2]=4
print(matrix)
```

It gives the following output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```